# Howto keep two references to the same object after serialization

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, control-state

Lets assume a class Foo like

```
[Serializable]
class Foo{
     int Id { get; set; }
     String Property1 { get ;set; }
     String Property2 { get ;set; }
}
```

I have a custom ASP control like

```
class MyControl : CompositeControl {
     object MyObject { get; set; }
     string PropertyName { get; set; }
}
```

I have an ASPX Page like

```
<MyControl id="mycontrol1" MyObject="<%# MyFoo %>" PropertyName="Property1"></MyControl>     
<MyControl id="mycontrol2" MyObject="<%# MyFoo %>" PropertyName="Property2"></MyControl>     

//code behind
Foo MyFoo { get; set; } 

protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e){
   if (Page.IsPostBack) return;

    //retrieve from Db:
    MyFoo = new Foo {
            Id = 123,
            Property1 = "Hello",
            Property2 = "World"
    };
}
```

The control is used to change the property specified by the PropertyName,lets assume the control just adds a * to the property, this is working fine. I Use the control-state to store the entity between postbacks. And there it is going wrong.

I create one object Foo.

I bind this one object to both controls

Both controls serialize the entity yo their control-state

Both controls add a * to the property. (frontend)

When postbacked, both controls deserialize the object from their control state.

I end up with two object:

```
//In mycontrol1.MyFoo
{
   Id = 123,
   Property1 = "Hello*",
   Property2 = "World"
}

//In mycontrol2.MyFoo
{
   Id = 123,
   Property1 = "Hello",
   Property2 = "World*"
}
```

Where I intended to have both instances to refer to the same object.

```
//mycontrol1.MyFoo and
//mycontrol2.MyFoo both referring to 
{
   Id = 123,
   Property1 = "Hello*",
   Property2 = "World*"
}
```

I Complete understand why this is happening, but I have no clue how to archive this.

**Edit:**
I think it actually has no much to see with ASP and contol-state. I think it can be solved in the serialization part. All I need to do I guess is somehow get both controls use a shared serializer and let this one understand that if it already has serialized an object with a given Id, it needs to return the same object.

If this requires the need of an interface like, that is acceptable.

```
interface IFoo {
    int Id {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: For better understanding, why is it important that the objects are the same? Can you consolidate the two objects into a single one afterwards?

Comment: Because that would require custom implementation on every page and therefor impede the benefits we are trying to archive by using a custom control. The control needs to know the complete object because it behave different based upon other properties than the one it controls.

Answer (score 1):

you could just wrap the retrieval in another cache layer.

e.g. 
override comparison on Foo to be based on Property1,Property2
create a global HashSet that contains Foo objects
create a function that takes as input Foo, and returns Foo

The function will see if there is already a Foo in the Hashset, if not, it will add it.
the function will always return the instance of Foo from the HashSet.

so finally you can say 
var Foo = GetFooFromSomewhere();
var MyFooInstance = MyFooCache.GetFoo(Foo);